# How to use both a static and dynamic library in the same project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I'm creating a C++ executable in Visual Studio, and I'd like to use two dependencies: one is available as a static library, and the other is available as a dynamic library. Is there a way to use both of them?

In Visual Studio, I usually set the `Runtime Library` parameter under `Code Generation` based off of what kind of library I'm using -- either `/MT` or `/MD`.  But if one external library is static and the other is dynamic, what's the correct setting?  Is it possible to use one of each, or do I need all of my libraries to be either static or dynamic?

Comment: Doesn't such a setting impact how **your** code is generated, not what libraries you can use?

Comment: If I switch my .exe project to `/MD`, for example, I get LNK2038 errors for my static library -- if I use `/MT`, I get linkage mismatch errors for my dynamic library.  I thought they only controlled how my project generated code, but it also seems to produce errors when using libraries created via a different linkage process.

Comment: Everything depends on what errors you get, and the setup of your projects. For solving those sort of issues: [mre] is a requirement (and producing one is a debugging technique).

Comment: What would be the best way to share a minimal multi-project sample?  It seems like it would be quite large and difficult to share.

On the other hand, are there any references or guides you could point me to about how to link multiple different kinds of libraries to a single project?

Comment: The problem is not caused by the different types of libraries you are loading, but by incompatible runtime library options used when libraries themselves were built. Apparently, your static library was built with /MT and the DLL was built with /MD. So you need to rebuild one of them.